# How can I float buttons on top of controls when the mouse enters (WPF)?

Tags: wpf

I want to make a control which will work like the tab header in Visual Studio 2010.

When you have a few tabs open (MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.xaml.cs, etc.) only the active tab has a close button visible, but when you hover the mouse over an inactive tab the close button appears, which means you can close any tab with one click.

It probably will be a border with text under the floated buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All WPF controls are containers, you can put a button inside a button for example.  You can have a layout manager to a control with the items you want in it.

For what you are asking about you could have a user control that has a TextArea and a Button in a StackPanel.  Then hide the button.  You then have the user control register for its MouseEnter and MouseLeave events and when the mouse is over you make the button visible, and when it leaves you hide it again.

Comment: I thought of that but then I thought it might be use too many resources (there will be ~50 controls at once on screen).  However, I think it might be the best way.

Comment: WPF is optimized for resource usage.  You asked for how you can do it, and that is above is how you can do it. It will not be any more resource intensive than the tabs used in VS10.  I think you are trying to over complicate a very simple thing. Always go for the simplest solution first and if it works then your done.  Don't optimize for performance before you know there is a performance problem.  Always get it working first than refactor from there if needed and only when needed.